# MongoDB chain lookup on 3 collections

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with the following case:

I have 3 collections:

agreements

```
{
   '_id': ObjectId('5a5c96be0e8945000fc6f504'),
   'condition': ObjectId('5a5c96be0e8945000fc6f503'),
   'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 15, 11, 55, 42, 370000),
   'ends_at': None,
   'starts_at': None,
   'updated_at': None
}
```

agreement_conditions

```
{'__v': 0,
   '_id': ObjectId('5a5f424ffb065a000f4e7988'),
   'amount': 14860,
   'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 17, 12, 32, 15, 900000),
   'currency': ObjectId('5a5c7858019f4e00015d8844'),
   'interest': 2.1,
   'interval': ObjectId('5a5c7858019f4e00015d8846'),
   'payback_interval': 4,
   'updated_at': None
}
```

agreement_intervals

```
  {'_id': ObjectId('5a5c7858019f4e00015d8846'), 'name': 'monthly'}
```

And at the end I want one collection that has all this data joined:

```
     '_id': ObjectId('5a5c96be0e8945000fc6f504'),
     'condition': {
                '_id': ObjectId('5a5f424ffb065a000f4e7988'),
                'amount': 14860,
                'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 17, 12, 32, 15, 900000),
                'currency': ObjectId('5a5c7858019f4e00015d8844'),
                'interest': 2.1,
                'interval': {'name': 'monthly'},
                'payback_interval': 4,
                'updated_at': None
},
     'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 15, 11, 55, 42, 370000),
     'ends_at': None,
     'starts_at': None,
     'updated_at': None
```

I made two aggregations agreements.aggregate lookup on agreement_conditions
and conditions.aggregate lookup on agreement_intervals but then then I have 2 commandcursors and how to join them again?

I am appreciating any help! :)

Comment: Are all relations one to one ? what is your mongo version ?

Comment: Agreements to conditions is 1:1, but then its n:1 -> agreement_intervals has only few fields. mongodb is 3.6 and I am using pymongo

Comment: Okay. I'm not a python user. I've provided the mongo shell query below. Hope you can transform it to python code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers. I did it now this way and it works. But any improvement ideas?

```
pipeline = agreements.aggregate([
    {"$lookup":
        {
            "from" : "agreement_conditions",
            "localField" : "condition",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "conditions"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind" : {"path": "$conditions", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True}},
    {"$lookup" :
        {
            "from" : "agreement_intervals",
            "localField" : "conditions.interval",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "conditions.interval_type"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind" : "$conditions.interval_type"},
    {"$lookup" :
        {
            "from" : "agreement_currencies",
            "localField" : "conditions.currency",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "conditions.currency"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind" : "$conditions.currency"},
    {"$lookup":
        {
            "from" : "agreement_statuses",
            "localField" : "status",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "status"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind" : "$status"},
    {"$project":
        {
            "starts_at": 1,
            "ends_at": 1,
            "created_at": 1,
            "updatped_at": 1,
            "status": {"name": 1},
            "conditions": {
                "payback_interval": 1,
                "amount": 1,
                "interest": 1,
                "currency": {"iso_code": 1},
                "interval_type": {"name": 1}
                }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: There is no need to $unwind. Have you tried my answer ?

Comment: Hey. Its not needed but I wanted clean dictionary with no array in it. Thats why I am using it. Your answer is throwing a python error: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'

Comment: You'll need 3.4 version. Can you upgrade to latest ?

Comment: Yeah. Use db.version() in mongo shell to check version.

Comment: It looks like that is the best you can do with 3.2. Consider update to latest version to make things simpler.